# Reference to System.Drawing.Image is unknown even with proper using directive

Tags: c#, namespaces, dependencies, .net-assembly

I have the following code to extract and save an image from PowerPoint file:

```
public static void GetImages()
{
    var doc = PresentationDocument.Open(@"D:\Peak Sourcing\Work\ppt_test\presenting.ppt", true);
    var presentationPart = doc.PresentationPart;
    var slidePart = presentationPart.GetPartsOfType<SlidePart>().FirstOrDefault();
    var imagePart = slidePart.GetPartsOfType<ImagePart>().FirstOrDefault();
    var stream = imagePart.GetStream();
    var img = Image.FromStream(stream);
    img.Save(@"D:\Peak Sourcing\Work\ppt_test\test-output.png");
}
```

However, class `Image` used in second last line does not exist. This are the namespaces that I have included in my program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using PowerPoint = Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint;
using Microsoft.Office.Core;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using System.Drawing;
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Check that `System.Drawing.dll` reference is present!

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1kcb3wy4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx